# namshi/jose 5.0.2 requires lib-openssl *

Tags: php

```
    "require": {
         "php": ">=5.5.9",
         "namshi/jose": "5.0.*",
         "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
         "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*",
         "dingo/api": "1.0.*@dev",
         "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.7.1"
    },
```

on composer install i am getting this **error**

> namshi/jose 5.0.2 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked
>   library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from
>   your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.

Comment: It means that you either haven't installed the openssl extension or the installed version doesn't meet the package requirements. You can find basic information about your PHP installation by running the [phpinfo()](http://php.net/phpinfo) function—though beware the command-line PHP (the one you use to run composer) may have a different `php.ini` file that browser PHP (the one you use to run Laravel), esp. if you use Linux.

Comment: openssl exists and i uncommented the ext: openssl.dll

Comment: Existence is a pretty good starting point. You could now run `phpinfo()` in order to find out if PHP can use the extension and, if so, what version is installed.

Comment: We'll assume everything else is correct (OpenSSL support  is true and reported versions match). The [README file](https://github.com/namshi/jose/tree/5.0.2) suggests: *You may find that you need to use this library in an environment where PHP's wrappers for OpenSSL do not work, or OpenSSL simply is not installed. This library uses OpenSSL to encrypt by default, but you can specify that you want to use PHPSecLib for a pure PHP implementation of RSA encryption.*